# PRODUCT VIEW CUSTOM HOW TO :::

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, product-relations

this is the code of the product view [CODE PRODUCT VIEW](http://paste.ofcode.org/ACSSjTxEBgDHm6XJKRhC7s)

I have try to change the design but it seams i get error 
i have to move related products ( look picture) i dont need text or size or something else there only the picture of the reated product)

hope someone can help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Magento CE 1.9 shop, and you are talking about the *related products* feature, then you need to understand a few things:

- Related products are built into the product view
- Related products must be setup manually for each product
- Your view must employ a related products child view

I can give you your answer by explaining the first point.

#### Related products are built into the product view

On a CE 1.9 shop using the `rwd/default` theme, you can learn how related products are setup by reviewing the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`. Inside of the `product.info` block declaration, you will find your clue:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
```

Because this block is declared *inside* of the `product.info` block, it is available to the template `catalog/product/view.phtml` (the template you referenced in your question). Knowing this, you have the *ability* to render related products anywhere in `view.phtml`.

Judging by your images, you want to insert related products beneath the *add-to-cart* button. To do that, just render the related products child block in your `view.phtml` template.

Here's an excerpt from your own code, modified to include related products.

```
...
<?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <div class="add-to-box">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?>

<!-- ADD RELATED PRODUCTS -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products'); ?>
<!-- /ADD RELATED PRODUCTS -->
...
```

This may not be the exact place where you want the products to appear, but you should get the idea. Now if what it outputs is not what you want, then you can edit the template, `catalog/product/list/related.phtml`

Comment: hi rick , ok - we have already assign all related products - we want use this as collor section . so if customer clik on it there will redirect to the other item (collor)

Comment: yes ther wher u see the image after add to cart we want to have the related products . thats right

Comment: but we dont use rw templte is custom template

Comment: If this is a custom template, it will probably still be named something similar, but live under a different folder, like `app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/catalog/product/view.phtml`, and the same is probably true for the `related.phtml` template. What might be different is the custom theme's `local.xml` file, which may exclude the related products block. If that's the case, you will have to add it back in using the block declaration I provided in my answer.

Comment: ok , but wich line i have to insert / and replace in product.view

Comment: It's 2 parts: 1). Make sure `related_product` is declared in your layout XML; 2). In your product view template, insert `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products'); ?>` where you need it. If you re-read my answer a few times above, it is all explained there.

Comment: @Yasin2018 were you able to solve your problem given this information? Please accept the answer if so.

Comment: i try now so i have to insert this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products'); ?> here after this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?> ? but than is after add this modul right ? but i want after add to cart so insert after this ?  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: is this ok ?  
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="icon-cart"></i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- ADD RELATED PRODUCTS -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products'); ?>
<!-- /ADD RELATED PRODUCTS -->

Comment: the file in catalog.xml is   </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Comment: Your `<block>` directive needs an `alias="related_products"` attribute, and your `<reference>` directive must target `product.info` _unless_ you know it should be a child of `right`. At this point I can't provide additional answers. The comment thread is getting too long.

Comment: @ Rick Buczynski i have try u code but is not working ,. i have try insert upsell and it works but not help me in this moment

Comment: it works now . the only problem i have that price , special price , name are there how remove them ?